# Conditional remove "proceed to checkout" button in Braintree for WooCommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, braintree

I'm using in the `wc_braintree_cart_payment_gateways` filter hook, this code to remove the "proceed to checkout" button in WooCommerce:

```php
add_filter( 'wc_braintree_cart_payment_gateways', function ( $gateways ) {

$categories   = [aaa,bbb];

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for product categories
    if ( ! has_term($categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {

            $gateways = []; 
            break;
        }else{  

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    }

    }
    
return $gateways;

} );
```

---

The first condition works as intented. The `remove_action` doesn't take affect. I'm not sure it's correctly placed? Any advice?

Comment: Why not overwriting a the template and place the check around the cart button? No need for actions/filters to be removed.

Comment: Because I'm doing it this way. And I want to understand why this code doesn't work rather than going with a total different solution.

Comment: The other solution is better in my eyes. Its much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the plugin you are talking about but adding a (lower) priorty number to the hook can provide the solution.

```php
function filter_wc_braintree_cart_payment_gateways ( $gateways ) {
    // Remove proceed to checkout button
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 ); 
    
    return $gateways;
}
add_filter( 'wc_braintree_cart_payment_gateways', 'filter_wc_braintree_cart_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );
```

---

If this works, you can extend your code

Comment: But this will remove the button regardless of the initial condition.

Comment: @t-bo As I already indicated in my answer **If this works, you can extend your code**. 
When you write code, do it in steps. This way you can determine after each step whether your code works before continuing. If the first step doesn't work, it makes little sense to add extra code. Since removing the button does not work, you can test this first without extras. If it works, your question has been resolved and you can add more conditions

Comment: Thank you for your help but I decided to go another way so I didn't have a chance to test.